# Tools to help process Akamai data logs?

Tags: logging, akamai

I'm digging through Akamai logs, downloading excel sheets, and then manually joining them so that I can do sorting of data to find top videos and referrers.  Are there any tools you know of to help with this kind of processing?  I'm looking for something like Urchin used to be for Apache logs, but for Akamai logs.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Akamai has some tools in the Portal for analytics although they have to part of your contract.

Otherwise, make sure you are creating the logs (also in the Portal) in one of the standard formats and you can use Webalyzer and Analog just like the Old Days.

Comment: There is also Indihian - http://indihiang.codeplex.com/ - Though it may crash if you have squillions of logs. Also, akamai has webservices for reporting that may be a bit easier to use.